# Как распознать таблицу в изображении на Python?

Tags: python, изображения, pdf, table, распознавание-символов

Как распознать таблицу в изображении на Python ?
Есть pdf документы (просто сканы документов бумажных), конвертирую каждый лист в изображение (с помощью wand) и распознаю текст на этих изображениях (с помощью pytesseract).
Бывают попадаются простые таблицы, так вот, как распознать таблицы, с помощью каких библиотек и их методов?